# Jboss 7 log4j configuration - JDBCAppender

Tags: java, log4j, jboss7.x, log4jdbc

Need help to setup Log4j JDBCAppender in standalone.xml in JBoss 7.1.1

I have tried as below but not working

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.1">
....
....
....
<custom-handler name="DB" class="org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender" module="org.apache.log4j">
  <level name="ERROR"/>   
  <properties>
    <property name="URL">Data Base URL</property>
    <property name="driver">edb-jdbc14</property>
    <property name="user">username</property>
    <property name="password">password</property>
  </properties>
  <formatter>
  <pattern-formatter pattern="INSERT INTO log_dtl(application_type,thread,class,method,line_no,level,log_date,message_key,message_dtl,message_desc,message_meta_data) VALUES('APP','%t','%c','%M','%L','%p','%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss}','%X{MESSAGE_KEY}','%m','%X{MESSAGE_DESC}','%X{MESSAGE_META_DATA}')" />
  </formatter>
  <drivers>
      <driver name="edb-jdbc14" module="com.edb-jdbc14.postgresDriver">
         <driver-class>com.edb.Driver</driver-class>
      </driver>
  </drivers>                
</custom-handler>
....
....
</subsystem>
```

Error Log

```
14:56:16,881 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015956: Caught exception during boot: org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException: JBAS014676: Failed to parse configuration
    at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:141) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:266) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:155) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_02]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: newValue is null
    at org.jboss.dmr.ModelNode.set(ModelNode.java:458) [jboss-dmr-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.logging.LoggingSubsystemParser.parsePropertyElement(LoggingSubsystemParser.java:898)
    at org.jboss.as.logging.LoggingSubsystemParser.parseCustomHandlerElement(LoggingSubsystemParser.java:610)
    at org.jboss.as.logging.LoggingSubsystemParser.readElement(LoggingSubsystemParser.java:169)
    at org.jboss.as.logging.LoggingSubsystemParser.readElement(LoggingSubsystemParser.java:113)
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:110) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.handleAny(XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.java:69) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.parseServerProfile(StandaloneXml.java:894) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readServerElement_1_1(StandaloneXml.java:330) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:127) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:100) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:110) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:69) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:133) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 3 more
```

This error is DB driver loading problem, but how to resolve this, or any alternative way to set up this

Answer (score 1):

The first issue is the `<driver/>` tag is not a valid tag for a `<custom-handler/>`.

The second issue is 7.1.1.Final will not allow log4j appenders to be defined as custom handlers. This would work with EAP 6.x (6.2 has all the bugs worked out), but without knowing much about how log4j implemented it's DB connection there could be potential issues with booting. For example the driver might not be on the CP yet so you might have to add an explicit module and dependency.

You might be best to just create a simple `java.util.logging.Handler` or `org.jboss.logmanager.ExtHandler` to handle your DB logging. It should be fairly simple to do and wouldn't rely on log4j. You could just add the handler to an `async-handler` for performance.

Comment: Is there no public/shared implementation of this? Should be a common issue...

Comment: What version of WildFly or JBoss EAP are you using?

Comment: I am using Wildfly 22.0.1.Final

Comment: In that case you should just be able to use a custom-handler, https://docs.wildfly.org/22/Admin_Guide.html#custom-handler. I guess there is not a great example there. I'm not too familiar with the appender so I'm not sure how it would look/work with a driver.

Comment: Thanks! I understand that I need to use a custom handler. But my initial question was if there is no already implementation on this (because I think is a common issue, I should not implement it ad-hoc on my server).